# Strange extra line after forloop in a tabular table

Tags: tables, loops

I'm trying to generate table lines (`tabular` environment) with `forloop` macro. I've got strange extra line after `forloop`.

```
\documentclass {article}

\usepackage [utf8] {inputenc}
\usepackage [english] {babel}
\usepackage{forloop}

\begin{document}

\newcounter{n}
\setcounter{n}{2}
\newcounter{i}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    1 head
        & 1 
        & 1 
        & 1 
            \\ \hline

    \forloop{i}{0}{\value{i} < \value{n}} {%
            1 
                & 1 
                & 1 
                & 1 
                    \\ \hline
    }
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Why that? Notice that if i add one hand-coded line after loop, than everything is fine.

Comment: LaTeX determines that the table has to be ended after starting a new row, because `\forloop` inserts unexpandable tokens. It's a problem already discussed in several questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The LaTeX kernel has the necessary tools, but they are (deliberately?) obfuscated to the casual <strike>reader</strike> user by (1) use of the `@` sign, (2) lack of documentation for the average user.

> [image: while loop num]

```
\documentclass {article}

\usepackage [utf8] {inputenc}
\usepackage [english] {babel}

\makeatletter 
% perhaps \ltxwhilenumtest would be here a better choice of name
\newcommand\ltxwhile [2]{\@whilesw {\ifnum #1}\fi {#2}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}\thispagestyle {empty}

\newcounter{n}
\setcounter{n}{4}
\newcounter{i}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    1 head
        & 1 
        & 1 
        & 1 
            \\ \hline
    \setcounter{i}{0}%
    \ltxwhile {\value{i} < \value{n}}
    {%
            \stepcounter{i}% careful with space coming from end of line
            1 
                & 1 
                & 1 
                & 1 
                    \\ \hline
    }
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: the important thing is that the last test, the one which will check that the loop is over, must not insert anything unexpandable: for example doing a `\def` is forbidden, or leaving a `\relax` or these sorts of things. The incrementation of the counter `i` is not expandable, but this is not the issue here, the issue is with how the test to stop is done.

Answer (score 1):

As egreg mentioned in a comment: it is well-known problem. Moderators feel free to close it as duplicate (I'd like to see the link to discussion of similar issue though).

So far I stick to a workaround: generate less by one rows in `\forloop` and then manually add code for the last line. Concerning example given in the question the solution is as follows.

```
\documentclass {article}

\usepackage [utf8] {inputenc}
\usepackage [english] {babel}
\usepackage{forloop}

\begin{document}

\newcounter{n}
\setcounter{n}{1} % !!! Max - 1
\newcounter{i}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    1 head
        & 1 
        & 1 
        & 1 
            \\ \hline

    \forloop{i}{0}{\value{i} < \value{n}} {%
            1 
                & 1 
                & 1 
                & 1 
                    \\ \hline
    }
    1 
        & 1 
        & 1 
        & 1 
            \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

**EDIT:** not a perfect solution, because text in first cell of last row is prefixed with additional horizontal space.