# longtable and for loop problem

Tags: longtable, loops

Can anyone explain me the difference betweeen the following to tables?
Why has the second one an additional line with one column?

```
\newcounter{kartonnr}

\newpage
\begin{longtable}{|p{1.5 cm}|p{.8 cm}|p{5 cm}|p{4 cm}|p{2.5 cm}|p{2 cm}|}
\hline
1&2&3&4&5&6\\\hline
1&2&3&4&5&6\\\hline
1&2&3&4&5&6\\\hline
1&2&3&4&5&6\\\hline
\end{longtable}

\begin{longtable}{|p{1.5 cm}|p{.8 cm}|p{5 cm}|p{4 cm}|p{2.5 cm}|p{2 cm}|}
\hline
\forloop{kartonnr}{1}{\value{kartonnr} < 5}{
1&2&3&4&5&6\\\hline
}
\end{longtable}
```

[image: My Output]

Comment: What packages, etc. are in your preamble? `longtable` and `forloop` aren't part of standard LaTeX, so to know how to solve your problem, we'll need to know your preamble as well.

Comment: you would get the same if you put `\relax` there or `{}` any non-expandable operation starts the next cell. You see the same in a standard tabular, this is unrelated to longtable

Comment: you can do `\forloop{kartonnr}{1}{\value{kartonnr} < 4}{%
1&2&3&4&5&6\\\hline
}1&2&3&4&5&6\\\hline` i.e. add last line by hand. (not that you need (%) to prevent unwanted space)

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/193327/strange-extra-line-after-forloop-in-a-tabular-table

Comment: hm the solutions don't help, as I need the counter of the loop to acces lines in a csv file. so I can' add the last line per hand as it comes from the file.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is using an *expandable* loop; `longtable` or `tabular` makes no difference, so in the example I use the latter.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\expfor}{mm}
 {
  \prg_replicate:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{|p{1.5 cm}|p{.8 cm}|p{5 cm}|p{4 cm}|p{2.5 cm}|p{2 cm}|}
\hline
\expfor{5}{1&2&3&4&5&6\\\hline}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: here i also can't access my csv file line by line

Comment: @user93039 You should look at the `csvsimple` package